# Simple Batch Script for Copying file to locations based on username

Tags: bash, shell, script, batch-file

I was wondering if someone can assist with this script, i have tried replacing the xcopy line with

```
echo %frompath%
```

and it just echos nothing, its as if the scope is not correct however i am unsure, mainly used to PHP, where you would be able to define a global variable outside the loop.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Lewis

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET frompath = "C:\from\"
SET preusername = "C:\to\"
SET postusername = "\folder\"

for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do (
    if not "%%a"="" (
        xcopy %frompath% %preusername%%%a%postusername%
    )
)

echo "Complete"
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your not quoting of pathes,
- the wmic flaw to produce doubled line endings and
- the fact that user names are padded with spaces are the problems you
  encounter.
- Your wrong usage of the set command as already mentioned by [JohnnyVegas](https://superuser.com/a/1333091/639112)

See this sample hex output of the wmic command to prove this:

```
> wmic UserAccount get Name|hex.exe
HEX:       +00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  0123456789abcdef
0000000000: 4E 61 6D 65 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  Name
0000000010: 20 20 20 20 0D 0D 0A 41  64 6D 69 6E 69 73 74 72      ...Administr
0000000020: 61 74 6F 72 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 0D 0D 0A 44 65  ator       ...De
0000000030: 66 61 75 6C 74 41 63 63  6F 75 6E 74 20 20 20 20  faultAccount
0000000040: 20 20 0D 0D 0A 47 61 73  74 20 20 20 20 20 20 20    ...Gast
0000000050: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 0D 0D 0A 48 6F 6D 65           ...Home
0000000060: 47 72 6F 75 70 55 73 65  72 24 20 20 20 20 20 20  GroupUser$
```

To solve the doubled `0x0D` you need another for.
The following batch only echos the xcopy command, if the output is OK remove the echo.

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET "frompath=C:\from\"
SET "preusername=C:\to\"
SET "postusername=\folder\"

for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name^|findstr "^[a-z]"') do (
    for %%b in (%%~a) do Echo=xcopy "%frompath%" "%preusername%%%a%postusername%"
)

echo "Complete"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an adminstrative command prompt?

Don't use spaces between '=' so change script to `set frompath="c:\from\"` - You will want to add the /s switch to the xcopy line so subdirectories are included.